# R: Installation of several packages had non-zero exit status

Tags: r, ggplot2, package, readr

I've just started to encounter the "had non-zero exit status" error when trying to install a package. This holds true for `readr` (below) and `ggplot2`.

Weirdly enough, the packages have previously (previous R session 5 minutes earlier) been loaded and used, but when loading them now, it generally results in the following error:

```
> library(readr)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘readr’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘pillar’
```

When trying to install the package again, it results in the following error;:

```
> install.packages('readr')
Error in install.packages : Updating loaded packages

Restarting R session...

> install.packages("readr")
also installing the dependencies ‘rlang’, ‘vroom’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘tzdb’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
          binary source needs_compilation
rlang      0.4.5 0.4.11              TRUE
vroom      1.2.0  1.5.4              TRUE
lifecycle  0.2.0  1.0.0             FALSE
readr      1.3.1  2.0.1              TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the packages which need compilation? (Yes/no/cancel) No
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘tzdb’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources? (Yes/no/cancel) No
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.5/rlang_0.4.5.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1171073 bytes (1.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.5/vroom_1.2.0.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2384663 bytes (2.3 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.3 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.5/readr_1.3.1.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 777189 bytes (758 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 758 KB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/kp/nyzw767n0qx2wpfwgplzg1bh0000gp/T//Rtmpu5HwNO/downloaded_packages
installing the source package ‘lifecycle’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/lifecycle_1.0.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 83389 bytes (81 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 81 KB

* installing *source* package ‘lifecycle’ ...
** package ‘lifecycle’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.5 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.10 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘lifecycle’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/lifecycle’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lifecycle’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/kp/nyzw767n0qx2wpfwgplzg1bh0000gp/T/Rtmpu5HwNO/downloaded_packages’
```

I've tried other suggestions in this forum, but none seemed to work for me (a. o. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59941229/installation-of-package-had-non-zero-exit-status) or [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/i-can-t-install-packages-on-r-studio-non-zero-exit-status/52135)).

I am using MacOS Big Sur and RStudio.

Comment: could you try installing package pillar via `install.packages('pillar')` ?

Comment: That results in the same error as shown above for ```readr```.

Comment: Just noticed:  you are using R 3.5.x.  That's very old, and binary packages aren't being built for it.  You should update R to the latest version (4.1.1, I think).

Comment: namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.5 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.10 is needed. Why don't you install it from source when prompted?

Comment: @user2554330: Funnily enough it did not occur to me that the version of R could be the problem here. It now works, thank you!